# jQuery Mobile collapsible panel and KNockjs observable array

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout-2.0

Can someone help me to figure out why my collapsible panel won't expand? My html markup with jquery mobile appears to be working. The data gets bound to the collapsible set via a foreach loop, but the panels will not expand.

html:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" class="ui-block-a" data-bind="foreach: opportunityData"> 
    <div data-collapsed="true" data-role="collapsible" >
        <h3>
            <span data-bind="text: name" />
        </h3>
        <p data-bind="text: company" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function OpportunityViewModel() {

        var self = this;
        self.opportunityData = ko.observable([]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'url....',
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                self.opportunityData(data)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
                alert(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
            }); //end ajax call
        }; //end viewmodel       

        ko.applyBindings(new OpportunityViewModel());           
    });
```

Comment: You should create an example of the issue, JSFiddle is a great place to do that.

Comment: I've even tried with a simper version on jsfiddle. Can someone just answer, does jQuery Mobile work with knockout? I've spent 2 days trying to get get what should be simple to work.

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lw5nQ/25/

Comment: Is there anyway to get the developers who created Knockout to take notice of this? There seems to be several post out there with the same issue. This could be a great product I'm not sure how this little functionality got overlooked. If there is a solution, Knockout, please provide or at least say it cannot be done with this version. I was truly hoping to use this framework Ive spent 2 days and paid for the Pluralsight tutorials, they were great, but like allways when it comes to something real world that you have to do, there's no example....Man I'm frustrated, please help!

Comment: Search Google. There are many Knockout JS and jQuerymobile tutorials out there.

Comment: Yes there are but none of them realy using jquery mobile and knockout together binding an oberverablearray to a collapsible panel.

Comment: Have you found the solution?  I'm having the same trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution, just create a **new out side div** then put **foreach** in that div:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: opportunityData">
   <div data-role="collapsible-set" class="ui-block-a" > 
       <div data-collapsed="true" data-role="collapsible" >
           <h3>
               <span data-bind="text: name" />
           </h3>
           <p data-bind="text: company" />
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```